# simple one page infinite scroll- angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a one-view page, including infinite scroll, for a mini project. I am running into issues when doing my scroll directive, inside the 'when-scrolled' directive definition. the cause of the error is: `var visibleHeight = elem.height();`the error I Get is:

> angular.js:10671 TypeError: elem.height is not a function

I want to understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
movieApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$location', 'movieService', '$timeout', '$element',
  function ($scope, $location, movieService, $timeout, $element) {
    window.scope = $scope;
    console.log($element);
    $scope.element = $element;
    $scope.loading = true;
    //pass the page number to getPopularMovies
    $scope.popularMovies = [];
    $scope.getInitialMovies = function () {
      $scope.pageNumber = 1;
      movieService.getPopularMovies(1).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.results[0]);
        $scope.popularMovies = response.data.results;
        $scope.loading = false;
      })
    }
    $scope.getInitialMovies();
    //pass the displayRecordCount to the backend on the scroll event, then concat the new records on to $scope.popularMovies
    $scope.getMoreMovies = function () {
      $scope.pageNumber++;
      movieService.getPopularMovies($scope.pageNumber).then(function (response) {
        $scope.popularMovies = $scope.popularMovies.concat(response.data.results);
      })
    }
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.getMoreMovies();
    }, 2000)
  }
]).directive('whenScrolled', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(arguments)
      var visibleHeight = elem.height();
      var threshold = attr.rpWhenScrolledThreshold || 20;
      bindScrollHandler();

      function bindScrollHandler() {
        elm.scroll(scrollHandler);
      }

      function scrollHandler() {
        var scrollableHeight = elm.prop('scrollHeight');
        var hiddenContentHeight = scrollableHeight - visibleHeight;
        if (hiddenContentHeight > 0 && visibleHeight > 0 && hiddenContentHeight - elm.scrollTop() <= threshold) {
          // Scroll is almost at the bottom. Loading more rows
          _.defer(function () {
            scope.$apply(attr.rpWhenScrolled);
            elm.off('scroll');
            $timeout(bindScrollHandler, attr.rpWhenScrolledThrottle || 0);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

view:

```
  <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="homeController"  when-scrolled="console.log('yo)"
             when-scrolled-throttle="500"
             when-scrolled-threshold="750">
            <div class="loader" ng-show="loading">
            </div>
            <!-- <pre>{{popularMovies | json}}</pre> -->
            <div ng-repeat="movie in popularMovies">
                {{movie.title}} + {{movie.release_date}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elem.height();
```

means, you are calling height function of element... but to get height, you have to get elements height property like

```
elem.height;
```

Comment: when I make that change the .scroll() function throws the same error, but that function should be there... I think there is a broader concept I am missing...

Comment: you have elem and elm, is it a typo ? also you have to chage console.log('yo) to console.log('yo')